# Moving hard disk from one laptop to the other: how to update OS drivers?

Tags: drivers, hard-disk, opensuse, hardware, hardware-compatibility

I have moved a hard disk containing openSUSE Leap 15.5 from one laptop to the other. The two laptops are from two different manufacturers.

The OS runs fine on the new laptop. But there are some glitches here and there. How can I make sure that the OS drivers are compatible with the new laptop?

#### Note

Previously, I had the experience of moving a hard disk containing Windows 10 between laptops. After the move, I had to update the device drivers on Windows according to the new hardware. I'm basically looking for an equivalent approach to openSUSE. I'm not sure, does it make sense?

## UPDATE

A glitch example was the freezing of the monitor when connecting a 2nd display by HDMI cable. Now this glitch is resolved by itself. I'm not sure why. Maybe a reboot or app restart resolved the problem.

Comment: Please define "glitches here and there". Also, are these internal or external HDDs?

Comment: @dr_ It's an internal HDD. Glitch example: when connecting a 2nd display by HDMI cable, the laptop monitor itself becomes non-responsive but the 2nd display works fine.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has anything to do with HDDs.

Comment: @dr_ Well, the HDD worked just fine on the previous laptop. But the new laptop has problems. So I guess some OS drivers are not compatible with new hardware. Is it a logical conclusion?

Comment: And the hardware can have its own restrictions too, e.g. if the laptop has two GPUs, the laptop monitor is usually connected to the power-efficient iGPU, while the external digital connectors are typically wired to the high-performance dGPU. Some laptops have a switching matrix that can connect any display to either GPU, but not all; and discovering the details of a multi-GPU implementation can be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be determining your hardware and the installed driver:

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA
```

Result e.g. ([taken from SUSE's help sites](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Configuring_graphics_cards))

```
 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT200 [GeForce GTX 260] [10de:05e2] (rev a1)
         Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:82cf]
         Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Now you will have to check via internet search if card and driver are compatible. If not, use `zypper` for de-/install the wrong/right driver, respectively.

I am unaware of any "update-all-drivers" tool. However the Support Database on SUSE's website has several entries regarding different graphics drivers which might help you.

Comment: An "update-all-drivers" tool might be a great product.